# Argument labels (_:) do not match any available overloads

Tags: ios, swift3, xmppframework

i want to use XMPP Framework and i download lib from github. The given below code gives an error. can someone help me out and i am taking guide from below link:
[XMPP FRamwork lib](http://www.stellar16.com/2016/03/17/register-send-message-xmppframework-swift/)

```
stream?.myJID = XMPPJID.init("user@localhost.com")
```

**Updated**:

[image: XMPP Suggestions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link](http://www.stellar16.com/2016/03/17/register-send-message-xmppframework-swift/) that you have given in question, is uses class method not the `init` to set `XMPPJID`.

```
stream?.myJID = XMPPJID.jid(with:"user@localhost")
```

Comment: the class is not avialable in xocode and it prompts error and if u see the the suggested answer on that forum some body sugeest to use init(). And also checkt the updated XMPP Suggestion.

Comment: Bro .jid is not available. i show the suggested list in updated para.

Comment: can u plz do me a favour. i cant understand. can u plz elaborate more or piece of code.

Comment: @MuhammadHaroon Have you try writing `XMPPJID.jidWithString("user@localhost")` ?

Comment: yes. xcode says: the jidWithString is replaced with "WithString".And when i fix that issue it says: withString is unavailable use object construction XMPPJID (string:)

Comment: @MuhammadHaroon Check my edited answer and try like that.

Comment: @MuhammadHaroon Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
stream?.myJID = XMPPJID.jid(with:"user@localhost")
```

instead of the line in your picture:

```
stream?.myJID = XMPPJID.("user@localhost")
```

Comment: it's not working and gives an error. read the above conversation with Nirav D

Comment: Well, now you got your answer. You should be more specific about the error you were getting.

Answer (score 0):

`RightClick` XMPPJID and `Jump to Definition`, you will see something like:

> public init!(string jidStr: String!)
>
> public init!(string jidStr: String!, resource: String!)
>
> public init!(user: String!, domain: String!, resource: String!)

So you can init a jid using:

- stream?.myJID = XMPPJID(string: "user@localhost")
- stream?.myJID =
  XMPPJID(string: "user@localhost", resource: "blabla")
- stream?.myJID =
  XMPPJID(user: "user", domain: "localhost", resource: "blabla")

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained your answer more than just a block of code with no comments.